# What is the difference between Authorization and Authentication in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I came over those two terms when reading the Django documentation and they were used to resemble seemingly different meanings. What is the difference?

Comment: Authentication: who you are. Authorization: what you are allowed to do.

Answer (score 7):

Straight out of the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/):

> The Django authentication system handles both authentication and authorization. Briefly, authentication verifies a user is who they claim to be, and authorization determines what an authenticated user is allowed to do. Here the term authentication is used to refer to both tasks.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I haven't been looking at the right place in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/):

> authentication verifies a user is who they claim to be, and authorization determines what an authenticated user is allowed to do